# Cannot type in Synapse on Ubuntu Mate 18.04 (similar problem with Tilda)

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-mate, synapse, tilda

I have used Ubuntu MATE 16.04 for some time now and both Synapse and Tilda have worked well. I have now recently installed Ubuntu Mate 18.04 and I'm having some problems with both programs. Synapse seems to work to start with, but after opening and closing the window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>) a couple of times it doesn't allow me to type anything; I'm typing, but nothing shows up, and I can't search in any way. I can still click with the mouse though, so it's not completely locked.

A similar thing happens with Tilda when I cannot hide the terminal with the regular key binding. It pops up when I want it to, and I can type in it, but I cannot hide it again.

I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: For more guaranteed result you can ask this question on https://ubuntu-mate.community/ . I do not use Tilda and Synapse, so I can't help.